# How do you turn off AuthComponent auto hash of password in CakePHP 2.2?

Tags: cakephp

I've spent the last 2 hours breaking my head over this. Basically, my table of users is not called **Users** but **Members**. I have added this code to my AppController.php but the password always gets hashed before the query is run.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'loginAction' => array(
            'controller' => 'members',
            'action' => 'login'
        ),
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'fields' => array('username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'),
                'userModel' => 'Member'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: what do you mean? on login the password needs to be hashed prior to the lookup. otherwise you could not compare it to the stored password..

Comment: I am storing the passwords in plain text for now just to see how the system is working. Until I start hashing the passwords, I want the AuthComponent to lookup the password in plain text only.

Comment: bad idea :) do it right from the beginning and everything will work as documented (and as the tutorials say it would).

Comment: I agree with what you say about no hashing being a bad idea (I always hash my passwords) but shouldn't cake work as expected (without hashing) instead of trying to force its own rules?

Comment: it doesnt force you to do anything. write your own Auth adapter that does not use any hashing. There you go. I am just saying that you are creating problems where there are none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are being overly paranoid, Fabian.  You want to turn off password hashing so you can check that the user login system is working properly, right? Well, there is no difference between logging in with a hashed or unhashed password.

Let's say my password is `Test123`.  If hashing is turned off, the only way I will be able to log in is if I enter `Test123` and it's exactly the same in the database. If hashing is on, my SHA1-hashed password is `8308651804facb7b9af8ffc53a33a22d6a1c8ac2` and so again the only way I can log in is if I enter the exact un-hashed representation of the password, which matches in the database.

In both cases, there is only one exact string that will allow me to log in.  So if it doesn't log in, you didn't enter the correct password that is in the database, hashed or unhashed.

So this leads me to assume that you are trying to test by pre-filling the database with passwords manually (e.g. `Test123`), that you then try to log in with.  Of course, you don't know the hashed version of the password so you put `Test123` in the database, and then when you try to log in, Cake is trying to use the hashed version of `8308651804facb7b9af8ffc53a33a22d6a1c8ac2` and the login doesn't work.

All you need to do is generate your passwords using an [online SHA-1 generator](http://hash.online-convert.com/sha1-generator). So enter `Test123`, get the hashed version it gives you, and put that in your database.  Then when you log in by entering `Test123`, Cake will hash it and match it to the hashed version in the database, and you will be logged in.

If it doesn't log in, you either entered the wrong password, or stored the wrong hash in the database.  Also, make sure your database password field is the correct type to store the whole of the hash. CHAR(40) is a good choice for SHA-1 passwords.

Answer (score 1):

In Cake 2.x auto hash password is switch off by default

Comment: I am running cake out of the box but it is still hashing the password.

Comment: check in your `beforeSave` of the `Member` model or `AppModel`. Cake 2.x does **not** [auto hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#hashing-passwords).

Comment: `beforeSave` is not defined in either.

Comment: login() will auto-hash though. that is his problem ;) he does not want to have any hashing, which is like the worst idea. see my comment above: doing it "right" from the start is the solution here.